# Set and return variable in one line in dart?

Tags: dart, syntax, properties

I think I remember something like this from python, maybe it was the walrus operator? idk.

but is there a way to set an attribute while returning the value? something like this:

```
class Foo {
  late String foo;
  Foo();
  String setFoo() => foo := 'foo';
}

f = Foo();
x = f.setFoo();
print(x);
// 'foo'
```

Comment: Normal assignment already does this.  You can simply use `String setFoo() => foo = 'foo';`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody forbids you to do it just like you said:

```dart
class Foo {
  late String foo;

  String setFoo() => foo = 'foo';
}

void main() {
    print(Foo().setFoo());
}
```

The only drawback of using the `late` modifier is that you can accidentally access the `foo` field before the initialization, which will cause a LateInitializationError.
To prevent this, you can use a nullable type for the field.

Moreover, you can just initialize the field inline:

```dart
String foo = 'foo';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it, that is, for the case that foo can be null:

```
class Foo {
  String? foo;
  Foo();
  String setFoo() => foo ??= 'foo';
}
```